# Invalidate() is not happening from Activity in Timer

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-canvas

This  is my code on Activity to Invalidate  the canvas  it is not invalidating. Means  onDraw()  is not getting called even once;

```
   public GraphView  view;
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

          view  = GraphView(this,null);
            runplotTimer();
  } 


      public void  runplotTimer()
    {
    Timer t = new Timer();
    //Set the schedule function and rate
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InvalidateTimer();
        }      
    },1000,40); 
}

  public void InvalidateTimer()
{
     this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                 //Log.d(ALARM_SERVICE, "Timer of 40 miliseconds");
                  view.InvalidateGraph();
            } 
        });
 }
```

on View class this is method which is gettting called from Activity. other OnDraw declaration is same as required.

```
   public void InvalidateGraph()
  {
     m_bCalledPlotRealTimeGraph = true;
         invalidate(chanX_count1, 0, chanX_count1+7, graphheight);


  }
```

Any help please ?

Comment: why it is not invalidating?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to make changes to the `View` on a `Timer` Thread, which will not work. You need to call `invalidate` on the main (UI) thread:

```
((Activity) view.getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        invalidate(chanX_count1, 0, chanX_count1+7, graphheight);
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand fully. My ChanX_count1 is on GraphView. what code you have written is on Activity. So Can I make ChanX_count1   as a static and access ChanX_count1 as GraphView.Chanx_count1?

Comment: @user2710860, you then need a reference to your `Activity`. You can use your `GraphView`'s `context` to do this. I will update my answer.

Comment: But using GraphView reference it is not working. I think it is creating a new object   or may be something else. I am not sure.

Comment: can any one help me please?

Comment: This is so simple  I found my answer by my self                        view = (GraphView) findViewbyId(R.id.GraphModel);

Answer (score 0):

you need to Start the Timer

```
 Timer t = new Timer();
//Set the schedule function and rate
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        InvalidateTimer();
    }      
},1000,40); 
t.start()
```

Instead of Timer use Handler.

```
class UpdateHandler implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run(){

       handler.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(0, 1000);
       handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);     

    }

}

private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())  {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                    //Call your draw method                 
                }

            }

    };
```

Inside onCreate and onResule write

```
  if( mupdateTask == null )
    mupdateTask = new UpdateHandler();
    handler.removeCallbacks(mupdateTask);
```

Call your handler using

```
handler.postDelayed(mupdateTask, 100);
```

Comment: Yes I can use handler and postDelayed but problem is : My DrawFunction should get called in 40 miliseconds.  So my question is whether View class will able to handle such fast speed